# Trocar imagem com mouse sobre campo de mapa de bits

Tags: html

Em página HTML com imagem tipo mapa com um menu de opções, quero mudar parte da imagem para outra do tamanho do campo definido para essa opção, ao passar o *mouse*, algo como `onfocus` ou `onmouseover`. Como faço, neste exemplo, para substituir (sobrepor) cada parte da imagem delimitada pelas coordenadas por outra como `opcao1foco.jpg`, `opcao2foco.jpg`? Obrigado desde já pelo apoio.

Exemplo:

```
<p>
  <map name="FPMap0">
    <area href="opcao1.htm" shape="rect" coords="238, 89, 333, 194">
    <area href="opcao2.htm" shape="rect" coords="348, 89, 542, 198">
  </map>
  <img border="0" src="menu.png" width="1067" height="274" usemap="#FPMap0">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem alguns plug-ins JQuery que poderão lhe ajudar neste aspecto:

### MapHilight

Fonte: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

Exemplo de uso: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

### ImageMapster

Fonte: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

Exemplos: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html